# adding product to shopping cart in angular 6

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add product to the shopping cart but i am getting:'$exists property do not exist on type AngularFireObject'. Product is added to the cart but if it exists in cart only quantity is updated. I am using angular 6 with firebase but the tutorial i am using is in angular 4.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Product } from '../models/product';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShoppingCartService {
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  private create() {
   return  this.db.list('/shopping-carts').push({
      dateCreated: new Date().getTime()
    });
  }

 async getCart() {
   const cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
  return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId).valueChanges();
}

private getItem(cartId, productId: string) {
  return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId);
}

  private async getOrCreateCartId(): Promise<string> {
    const cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId');
    if (cartId) { return cartId; }
    const result = await this.create();
    localStorage.setItem('cartId', result.key);
    return result.key;

  }

 async addToCart(product: Product) {
     const cartId =  await this.getOrCreateCartId();
     const item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.key);
     item$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
       item => {
         if(item$.$exists) {
           item$.update({ quantity: quantity + 1 });
         } else {
           item$.set({ product: product, quantity: 1});
         }
       }
     );
  }
}
```

shopping-cart.service.ts =>

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../models/product';
import { ShoppingCartService } from '../services/shopping-cart.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-card',
  templateUrl: './product-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-card.component.css']
})

    export class ProductCardComponent {
      @Input('product') product: Product;
      @Input() showActions = true;
      @ Input() shoppingCart;

      constructor(private cartService: ShoppingCartService) { }

      addToCart() {
        this.cartService.addToCart(this.product);
      }

      getQuantity() {
        if (!this.shoppingCart) { return 0; }
        const item = this.shoppingCart.items[this.product.key];

        return item ? item.quantity : 0;
      }

}
```

product-card.components.ts =>

Comment: Try `return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId);` you not have to get the returning data you know this is the right object to update or set. Snapshotchanges and valuechanges only are used to get the data not update or set it.

Comment: Is there a way to check if object exists in firebase?

Comment: well you can first get the object with snapshotchanges and then without

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `item$.$exists` you need to use `item$.exists()`